# Any reason not to monitor ALL event types (operations) in triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, performance, triggercontext

Is there any drawback on having defined all possible Trigger events / operation `before x, after x, before y, after y` in the header of a trigger even if I don't use them in my code?

As most decent Apex developers do I don't code inside `.trigger` files. I always delegate the work to a Trigger Handler Apex class. In the past I spend some time finding strange bugs where Trigger code did not work only to find out later that the event was missing in the trigger file.

An easy solution would be to always define them all in the first place

```
trigger Plural on Singular__c (before insert, after insert, ..., before undelete, after undelete) {
    TriggerHandler.delegate();
}
```

**Is there any (performance) drawback when doing this?**

Answer (score 3):

I'd say there is, given that it would get triggered for every operation regardless of whether the handler actually does anything. Of course that overhead would be minimal so it's unlikely to cause an issue except in the most extreme cases where you're close to that 10 second CPU limit.

Personally I always name triggers after the events they're designed to handle, partly because I don't always put the code outside of the trigger — it depends largely on the context and whether the bulk of a framework is overkill or not.

So in this case if the trigger only catered for `before insert` I'd name it "Singular_BeforeInsert". Gets a bit unweildy with many operations perhaps, but at least it does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to have a trigger per event per object, because it fits in well with the trigger switching pattern we use. I will check whether I want the Singular__c BeforeInsert trigger to run in the BeforeInsert trigger and then choose to run or not run the handler method. It irks me a little to see triggers that run on all events that then start off with

```
if(trigger.isBefore())...
if (trigger.isUpdate())...
```

because it leaves me thinking "we knew this a minute ago. The trigger knew what event it was running for, and you've munged it into an all-events bucket, and now you're sifting through that bucket to separate them back out...".

I prefer to have a trigger per event even though I'm still not convinced between a single trigger handler method, and a trigger handler method per event.

I also prefer it for clarity, as the Singular_BI trigger runs on Singular BeforeInsert, Singular_AI runs on Singular AfterInsert, and it's obvious to all. Your case demonstrates this - when you have a Singular_AllEvents type trigger, and it doesn't cover all events, you're scratching your head for a while wondering why things aren't happening.

In your circumstance, if you're keen to have a single trigger per object, I'd take the (probably tiny) CPU hit @LaceySnr mentions just to start every trigger's life covering all events, as it seems you're expecting that to be the case. The designtime convenience and clarity for the developers on the system is probably worth the slight-to-imperceptible drag on runtime. (YMMV, no benchmarks have been performed).